# React expect string or class/function but got object, when using Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Input)`. React-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-phone-number-input

I am using `react-phone-number-input` and some custom inputs.

I would like to use my custom input within this library.

as you can see from the [Documentation](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/docs/index.html#phoneinputwithcountry), I can use the following props :

`inputComponent`

to use a custom input, as long as

```
Phone number <input/> component.

Receives properties:

value: string — The formatted value.
onChange(event: Event) — Updates the formatted value from event.target.value.
onFocus() — Is used to toggle the --focus CSS class.
onBlur() — Is used to toggle the --focus CSS class.
Other properties like type="tel" or autoComplete="tel" that should be passed through to the DOM <input/>.
Must also either use React.forwardRef() to "forward" ref to the <input/> or implement .focus() method.
```

So I have done the following :

```
<PhoneInputWithCountry inputComponent={<Input />}/>
```

With my input beeing the following (It is simplified, but globally it looks like this) :

```
export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  (
    {
      value,
      disabled,
      onBlur,
      prefixComponent,
      suffixComponent,
      ...rest
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          disabled={disabled}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          ref={ref}
          value={value}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

I think all looks fine, but I get prompted with

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
> Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Input)`.

I do not understand at all what is wrong here.

Comment: Maybe the error is from `{...rest}`